# Initialize a val from a secondary constructor

Tags: scala

I have the following class representing some amount of money:

```
class Money(initDollars: Int, initCents: Int){

  require (initDollars >= 0 && initCents >= 0)

  private def this(positive: Boolean, initDollars: Int, initCents: Int) = {
    this(initDollars, initCents)
    //this.positive = positive
  }

  val positive: Boolean = true
  val dollars = initDollars + initCents/100
  val cents = initCents % 100
  private val totalAmount = dollars * 100 + cents

  def unary_- = new Money(!positive, dollars, cents)
}

object Money{
  def apply(initDollars: Int, initCents: Int) = new Money(initDollars, initCents)
}
```

The amount can also be negative and I want to create it like this:

```
val am = -Money(1, 20)
```

So I want to initialize `val positive` from a secondary constructor, but I can't do it, because it's reassignment to val. I also can't add `val` in the list of parameters to secondary constructors. Could someone help?

Comment: By the way: in this encoding, there are *two* different ways of encoding `0`: `Money(true, 0, 0)` and `Money(false, 0, 0)`. Be sure to handle both cases when doing arithmetic and equality!

Comment: I agree, I think it's better to store just the sum in cents like -123. Then I don't need to keep track of the boolean flag.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I tried to do it without the flag. So my main private constructor takes totalCents and secondary constructor takes dollars and cents. My problem now is that I can't check for positive values in secondary constructor, because I have to call `this(initDollars * 100 + initCents)` in the first line. Code is here: http://pastebin.com/hDK3JPGZ. Could you look please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do it the other way around.

```
class Money private (pos: Boolean, initDollars: Int, initCents: Int) {

  require (initDollars >= 0 && initCents >= 0)

  def this(initDollars: Int, initCents: Int) = {
    this(true, initDollars, initCents)
  }

  val positive: Boolean = pos
  val dollars = initDollars + initCents/100
  val cents = initCents % 100
  private val totalAmount = dollars * 100 + cents

  def unary_- = new Money(!positive, dollars, cents)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in order to achieve what you want, you have to do the following structural modification:

```
class Money(initDollars: Int, initCents: Int, positive: Boolean)
```

That way, you can then write a constructor that has *less* parameters without a problem (e.g. omitting "positive"). Doing it the other way around will be hard in Scala, if you want to stick to immutable values.

If you have the following declaration in your class body:

```
val positive: Boolean = true
```

You won't be able to change `positive` anymore, no way around it :)

Comment: thanks! I upvoted your answer. But since @n.m was first, I accepted his one.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to one constructor, add positive to the end and give it a default value of true like this:

```
positive:Boolean = true
```

This way if defaults to true if not supplied. Then do the same for your apply function and invoke the 3 field constructor in apply.